# bitrix получить все уроки по ид курса

Tags: битрикс

пробую так. но выдает абсолютно все уроки

```
if (CModule::IncludeModule("learning"))
{
    echo $COURSE_ID;
    $res = CLesson::GetList(
                    Array("SORT" => "ASC"), Array("ACTIVE" => "Y", "ID" => $COURSE_ID)
    );
    while ($arLesson = $res->GetNext())
    {
        echo "Lesson name: " . $arLesson["LESSON_ID"] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

по примеру https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/learning/classes/clesson/getlist.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В фильтре у Вас допущена опечатка, вместо `"ID" => $COURSE_ID` должно быть `"COURSE_ID" => $COURSE_ID`, потому что ID - это идентификатор самого урока, а не курса.

Если хотите использовать получить список уроков курса, зная ID курса, то Ваш код должен быть таким:

```
<?php
if (CModule::IncludeModule("learning")) {
    $COURSE_ID = 8;
    $res = CLesson::GetList(
        Array("SORT"=>"ASC"), 
        Array("ACTIVE" => "Y", "COURSE_ID" => $COURSE_ID)
    );
    while ($arLesson = $res->GetNext()) {
        echo "Lesson name: ".$arLesson["NAME"]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

P.S. Будьте внимательны при использовании примеров из [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/learning/classes/clesson/getlist.php).

Answer (score 0):

А еще можно воспользоваться https://github.com/elenasimchenko/bitrix-learning-orm

```
$res = \Learning\LessonTable::getlist([
  'filter' => [
    'Learning\LessonEdges:TARGET.SOURCE.COURSE.ID' => $courseId, 
  ],
  'select' => [
    'ID',
    'NAME',
  ]
]);
echo $res->getSelectedRowsCount();
print_r( $res->fetchall() );
```